# How to resize(shrink/grow) UILabel on using pinch gesture recognizer?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using `UILabel` and have assigned pinch gesture recognizer to it. When I pinch the label I have written function which consists of the below code:

```
CGFloat scale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
label.font.pointSize = label.font.pointSize * scale;
```

This code increases/decreases the font size, but cannot resize the label. I have also used the below code to transform the label which transforms the whole label but the quality is lost:

```
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);
```

I need some work-around that can resize (width/height) of the label considering the font-size.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: If you have the scale why not just adjust the frame of the label?

Comment: Yes,I can adjust the width and height of the label but cannot change the left and top positions of the label according to shrink/grow.

Comment: I got some work around to find the center of the label before pinching,stored it in some variable and then reassign the center position to the label again after finishing the pinch.Here is the code at the pinch start:

CGPoint centerPoint;   
centerPoint = CGPointMake([[sender view] center].x, [[sender view] center].y);

And then after the pinch completes I used:
[[sender view] setCenter:centerPoint];

Comment: I sugest to update your question or answer if yourself, since comments doesn't show indentation. It will be much clearer outside of the comment section.